# CodedUI dropdown selection

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am trying to hand code my g mail signup form , i want to select month from drop down , but i was able to click the drop arrow by searching the properties from Test Builder.and not possible to find the property from month content , tried with Test Builder .

can any one show me how to select that particular drop down

Thank you ,

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you let Coded UI show you what to do. Try creating a (sandbox) Coded UI project and use the Coded UI record and generate tool to perform the required actions. Then copy the ideas from the automatically generated code. If the Coded UI recorder cannot generate suitable code then the problem is hard.