# how to select an item in winform combobox using c# automation code

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, listbox, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to select a combobox item using the following code, I am not sure if i am doing it in a right way because the error message says the listbox was not found.

how do i locate the listbox control within the combobox xontrol?

I am working on coded ui, but i am writing the manual scripts and not the recorded code.
To identify control properties, i am using the record and playback tool.
I am able to identify combobox control properties but not the listbox control within combobox.

Thanks in advance.

```
 string kk;
 kk = "BREITENBUSH HOT SPRINGS";


 Mouse.Click(DataEntryControls.combobtn);

 for (int i = 0; i < DataEntryControls.DataEntryFieldNameCombo.Items.Count; i++)
 {
    if (kk.Equals(DataEntryControls.DataEntryFieldNameCombo.Items[i].ToString()))
    {
       // when its found click on that item
       Mouse.Click(DataEntryControls.DataEntryFieldNameCombo.Items[i]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382044/codedui-dropdown-selection/15391617#15391617

Answer (score 0):

Try locating the combo box items by searching for a ListBoxItem type of control instead of a ListBox.