# Why can't Coded UI extract the column header text within a WPF datagrid specifying an Automation ID for the column header?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to verify the text of a column header in a WPF datagrid using Coded UI. I'm using the a fully coded approach rather than using the record and playback approach as I feel it gives me more flexibility. However I'm having difficulty getting Coded UI to find the control. I'm trying to verify the Display Text property in the following control:

[image]

As this does not have an Automation ID I searched for the (parent) column header object:

[image]

The code snippet below is what I used to extract the column header text:

```
WpfTable table = new WpfTable("mainWindow");
table.SearchProperties.Add(WpfTable.PropertyNames.AutomationId, "gridId");
table.WaitForControlReady(15000);
table.SetFocus();

WpfCell cell = new WpfCell(table);
cell.SearchProperties.Add(WpfControl.PropertyNames.AutomationId, "columnHeaderId");
cell.WaitForControlExist(5000);

string clientIdHeaderDisplayText = (new WpfText(clientIdHeader)).DisplayText;
```

The issue I'm facing is that I keep getting this error:

> TestMethod threw exception: 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException:
>   The playback failed to find the control with the given search
>   properties. Additional Details:  TechnologyName:  'UIA' FrameworkId: 
>   'Wpf' ControlType:  'Text'
>   ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has
>   been returned from a call to a COM component.

The exception is thrown whenever the last line in the above snippet is executed. Could someone help me sort this out please?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15391617/546871

Comment: @AdrianHHH I tried that approach and it works but since the recorder generates a UIMap it's able to create a "path" from the main window -> custom user control -> grid -> column header presenter -> column header -> the text block. I'm not able to do it as extensively since some of they don't have automation IDs. I created a path to the textblock using whatever IDs available (incl. the column header presenter's auto generated ID) but the result is still the same.

Comment: @AdrianHHH could you post your suggeestion as an answer here? I tried it again and since it worked I could mark it as the correct answer. I think I might have missed one of the levels on my previous attempt.

Comment: Closing this question as a duplicate of the other answer may be more appropriate. It the other answer is useful then you could vote on it.